# ADB2C - Architecture query on HA/DR

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I am new to ADB2C and wanted to know in case if we need to consider any architectural things before deciding ADB2C. As per Microsoft documentation, it provide 99.99% SLA but nothing is mentioned about architecture. What if the region(s) goes down? is it something already handled by Azure and we don't need to worry?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: B2C is similar to AAD - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-architecture

Answer (score 0):

AAD is a [highly-distributed system](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/advancing-azure-active-directory-availability/), which will continue to work even if a single region goes down. For B2C especially, you have to consider that the SLA only covers specific scenarios:

> We guarantee at least 99.99% availability of the Azure Active Directory B2C services. The services are considered "available" in the following scenarios:
>
> - The services are able to process user sign-up and sign-in to the Azure AD B2C services.
> - Azure AD B2C successfully emits the authentication and authorization tokens required for users to log into applications connected to the service.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/legal/sla/active-directory-b2c/v1_1/